# Django custom management command with variable length of args list

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a custom django management command.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option(
            "-i",
            "--user_id",
            dest="user_id",
        ),
        make_option(
            "-f",
            "--fields",
            dest="fields"
        ),
    )
```

I need `fields` to consist of multiple elements. I know about `nargs` but I need to specify an exact number. My `fields` can vary from 1 to 5 elements. Is there a proper way to work with such args lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this automatically. But you can work with a different action type:

```
option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
    make_option(
        "-i",
        "--user_id",
        dest="user_id",
    ),
    make_option(
        "-f",
        "--fields",
        dest="fields",
        action="append",
    ),
)
```

Now supply multiple field names at the command line like so:

```
./my_program -u my_user -f field1 -f field2 -f field3
```

`options['fields']` will then contain a list of field names or None. You can check for this (and the fact that the list is longer than five elements) and print an error message.